# Referencing a dynamic cell in VBA function for creating an Index of Worksheet with that same name

Tags: vba, excel, dynamic

I have 3 worksheets: Table of Contents, Sheet Generator, and Sheet 1.

The "Sheet Generator" worksheet is where the unique sheet name is created, we will call the unique sheet "Sheet 1". At the point of generating "Sheet 1", the macro also inputs the unique name "Sheet 1" into a new line in in "Table of Contents" worksheet.

This process happens many, many times and I can end up with 30 new uniquely named sheets.

Currently I am manually adding a hyperlinks to these sheets so I can jump to each one a little quicker, than having to scroll horizontally for days. I want to add into the macro that generates the unique name into the "Table Of Contents" a hyperlink to that sheet so I no longer have to do it manually.

Doing it manually looks like this when the "Table of Contents" has "Sheet 1" written in cell A3.

```
Sub TestINDEX2()

Range("A3").Select
ActiveSheet.Hyperlinks.Add Anchor:=Selection, Address:="", SubAddress:= _
    "'Sheet 1'!ac", TextToDisplay:="Sheet 1"

End Sub
```

The unique name of the sheet is generated in cell "NB2" in the "Sheet Generator" worksheet. But the hyperlink needs to be in cell "A3" in the "Table of Contents" worksheet.

I want it to do this:

```
Sub TestINDEX2()

Range("A3").Select
ActiveSheet.Hyperlinks.Add Anchor:=Selection, Address:="", SubAddress:= _
    "'Sheet Generator'!NB2", TextToDisplay:="'Sheet Generator'!NB2"

End Sub
```

But, this obviously doesn't work....

Any suggestions on how to reference a dynamic cell into a macro that adds hyperlinks?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this is what you're looking for:

```
Dim wb As Workbook
Dim wsToC As Worksheet
Dim wsGen As Worksheet
Dim rDest as Range

Set wb = ActiveWorkbook
Set wsToC = wb.Sheets("Table of Contents")
Set wsGen = wb.Sheets("Sheet Generator")
Set rDest = wsToC.Cells(wsToC.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Offset(1)
If rDest.Row < 3 Then Set rDest = wsToC.Range("A3")

wsToC.Hyperlinks.Add Anchor:=rDest, _
                     Address:="", _
                     SubAddress:="'" & wsGen.Range("NB2").Text & "'!A3", _
                     TextToDisplay:=wsGen.Range("NB2").Text
```

Comment: Thank you for the comment, this is the correct logic I have been looking for. The only thing I need to add is, how do you make it so it will populate the hyperlinks from A3 downwards?

Answer (score 1):

assuming sheets names list is in "Sheet Generator" sheet from cell A3 downwards, you may try this:

```
Option Explicit

Sub BuildHyperlinks()
    Dim cell As Range
    With Worksheets("Sheet Generator")
        For Each cell In .Range("A3", .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp))
            ActiveSheet.Hyperlinks.Add Anchor:=Selection, Address:="", SubAddress:= _
            "'" & cell.Value2 & "'!A1", TextToDisplay:=cell.value
        Next
    End With
End Sub
```